# How to use params[:search] as input in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use params[:search] as input.I have below code in controller.

```
def search
@student = Student.search(params[:search])
    if @student.present?
  flash[:notice] = 'Student is available,Please create'
  redirect_to :action => :new
 end
 if @student.nil?
  @studentId=params[:search] //Not working
 # @studentId="123"//working 
end
end
```

Above code if am using params[:search] i am getting error.But if i am using @studentId="123" which is working fine.How to pass params as input?

Comment: What do you mean, "not working"? What errors are you getting? Also, your code has syntax errors (which might just be copy and paste errors, but it is hard to tell). You have an unclosed if statement. And, a stray curly bracket.

Comment: Thanks.I have given sample.But requirement is pass params[:search] values as input

Comment: Can you please provide the implementation of the method search in Student class?

Comment: "Requirement is pass params[:search] values as input". Pass params[:search] values *where*? As input to *what*?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a view file `search.html.erb` file and you are implementing `search` method in `StudentsController`:

Make sure when ever you navigate to your view file, it has search param in the URL:  Ex: `localhost:3000/search?search=123`. This way `@studentId = params[:search]` will be `@studentId = "123"` and you can work on it without error. But if you don't pass `search` param in URL, then `@studentId` will be `nil` and thus you'll get error. Ex: Just `localhost:3000/search` will throw you error.

Also I think you need to use `@student = Student.find(params[:search])` instead of `@student = Student.search(params[:search])`